# Get results of SQL Query as string in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, average, rails-activerecord

when i run a complicated sql query from the command line like this

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 < queries.sql
```

i get a result like this

```
Competency Name|Component Name|3.77|4.0|0.23
Another Competency Name|Another Component Name|3.77|4.0|0.23
```

which i can easily parse like this

```
hidden_strengh_strings = results.split("\n")[1..-1];
hidden_strengh_strings.each do |hidden_strength_string|
  hidden_strengh_values = hidden_strength_string.split("|");

  hidden_strength = {}
  hidden_strength.merge!(:competency => hidden_strengh_values[0]);
  hidden_strength.merge!(:component => hidden_strengh_values[1]);
  hidden_strength.merge!(:reviewer_average_score => hidden_strengh_values[2]);
  hidden_strength.merge!(:reviewee_average_score => hidden_strengh_values[3]);
  hidden_strength.merge!(:exceedance => hidden_strengh_values[4]);

  hidden_strengths << hidden_strength
end
```

but i have no idea how to get these results from within ActiveRecord.

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(File.open(Rails.root.join('queries.sql'), 'r') { |f| f.read } );
```

doesn't seem to do what i want it to.

i'd be happy to take any approach to solve this problem. even rewriting the sql from within the ActiveRecord DSL. but i need help finding the right direction.

thanks : )

Comment: What's the content of queries.sql? If you can run them from ActiveRecord wont that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nishant lead me to the solution.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
```

Works fine its just that the query started with:

```
select 'HIDDEN STRENGTHS';
```

so exec ended at the semicolon.

Thanks!